# Update existing data based on sku?

Tags: magento-1.9

Update existing data based on sku ?

I am using a custom module for manage device. In which, we have an option to import devices via csv. It is working fine but when we import csv it always create new entry for a device.

I want to update existing device not create new entry, if device title is match. How can I achieve ?

I am using below code in model :

```
  <?php 
    class Custom_Devices_Model_Import extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
    {
        protected function _construct(){
           $this->_init("devices/devices");
        }

        protected function csvToArray($file, $delimiter=null) 
        { 
          if (($handle = fopen($file, 'r')) !== FALSE) { 
            $i = 0; 
            while (($lineArray = fgetcsv($handle, 0, $delimiter, '"')) !== FALSE) { 
              for ($j = 0; $j < count($lineArray); $j++) { 
                $arr[$i][$j] = $lineArray[$j]; 
              } 
              $i++; 
            } 
            fclose($handle); 
          } 
          return $arr; 
        } 

        public function getCsvData($file)
        {
            $feed = $file;
            $data = $this->csvToArray($feed, ',');      
            $count = count($data);  
            if($count == 0):
                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError("CSV file is empty!");
                return true;
            endif;
            $device = Mage::getModel('devices/devices')->getCollection();

            foreach($device->getData() as $value):
                $alldevice = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $value['title']);
                $devices[] = trim($alldevice);
            endforeach;



            $columnsCount = $data[0];
            $coloumnArray = '';
            /******** get colomun name from CSV ************/
            for($i=0; $i<count($columnsCount); $i++)
            {
                if(trim($columnsCount[$i]) == 'SKU'):
                    $countColoumn[] = 'sku';
                elseif(trim($columnsCount[$i]) == 'SKU/Child description'):
                    $countColoumn[] = 'title';
                elseif(trim($columnsCount[$i]) == 'Device Image URL'):
                    $countColoumn[] = 'filename';
                elseif(trim($columnsCount[$i]) == 'Status'):
                    $countColoumn[] = 'status';
                elseif(trim($columnsCount[$i]) == 'Release date'):
                    $countColoumn[] = 'releasedate';
                elseif(trim($columnsCount[$i]) == 'Device Type'):
                    $countColoumn[] = 'mobile_tablet';
                else:
                    $countColoumn[] = strtolower(str_replace(' ','_',$columnsCount[$i]));
                endif;  
            }   

$device_list=array('1'=>'Smartphones', '2'=>'Tablets', '3'=>'Laptops', '4'=>'Consoles', '5'=>'eReaders', '6'=>'Smartwatches', '7'=>'Music Players', '8'=>'Monitors', '9'=>'Rugged Handhelds', '10'=>'PDAs', '11'=>'All-In-Ones', '12'=>'TVs', '13'=>'SatNavs', '14'=>'Cars', '15'=>'Cameras');

            try{
                if(in_array('collection_id',$data[0])):
            /************** UPDATE DATA ****************/
                unset($data[0]);



                    foreach($data as $v)
                    {                               
                        $k = 0;     
                        foreach($v as $kz)
                        {
                            $kz=$kz=='Disabled'?'1':$kz;


                            /* if(strtolower($kz)=='tablet'){
                                $kz = 1;
                            }elseif(strtolower($kz)=='smartphone'){
                                $kz = 2;
                            } */


                            if($countColoumn[$k] == 'collection_id' && $kz == ''):
                                break;
                            elseif($countColoumn[$k] == 'collection_id' && $kz != ''):
                                $save = Mage::getModel('devices/import')->load($kz);                        
                            endif;
                            if($k != 0):
                                $pushrArray[$countColoumn[$k]] = $kz;
                                $col = ucwords($countColoumn[$k]);
                                $row = set.$col;
                                $save->$row($kz);
                            endif;                  
                            $k++ ;
                        }
                        $j++ ;
                        $save->save();                          
                    }
                else:
                /************** INSERT DATA ****************/
                    unset($data[0]);
                    $j = 0;
                    $countData = 0;
                    foreach($data as $v)
                    {
                        $k = 0;     
                        foreach($v as $kz)
                        {

                            $key = array_search(strtolower($kz), $device_list);
                            if ($key !== false) {

                                $kz = $key;
                            }

                            $kz=$kz=='Disabled'?'1':$kz;

                            if( $countColoumn[$k] == 'title' && (in_array(trim($kz),$devices))):
                                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError('Device '.$kz.' already in device list');
                                break;
                            endif;
                            if(($countColoumn[$k] == 'title' && $kz == '')):                            
                                break;
                            endif;
                            $pushrArray[$countColoumn[$k]] = $kz;
                            $k++ ;
                        }
                        $j++ ;
                        if(count($pushrArray) > 0):
                            $save = Mage::getModel('devices/import')->setData($pushrArray)->save();
                            $countData++;
                        endif;      
                    }       
                endif;
                if($countData > 0):
                    Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addSuccess(Mage::helper("adminhtml")->__("Devices was successfully saved"));
                endif;  
            }catch(Exception $e)
            {
                Mage::getSingleton("adminhtml/session")->addError('');
            }
        }   

        protected function to_camel_case($str, $capitalise_first_char = false) {
          if($capitalise_first_char) {
            $str[0] = strtoupper($str[0]);
          }
          $func = create_function('$c', 'return strtoupper($c[1]);');
          return preg_replace_callback('/_([a-z])/', $func, $str);
        }


    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Can you check if you get data after you use `$save = Mage::getModel('devices/import')->load($kz);` code by adding `var_dump($save->getData())`

Comment: @JaiminSutariya, Thanks for the reply. I have completed the task.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into MAGMI as this does exactly what you need it to do and connects directly into your database so is a whole of a lot faster.

http://wiki.magmi.org/index.php?title=Magmi_Wiki